# How do i get the sum of values of an Object Array :java8

Tags: java, arrays, object, functional-programming, java-stream

in variable "a" i create a `double` array, and in "maxA" i get the sum of the values. Now in variable "b" i create an object array with double values, now i want to have the sum of these values using the `stream` value. thanks for help

```
  double[] a = new double[] {3.0,1.0};
  double maxA = Arrays.stream(a).sum();

  ObjectWithDoubleValue  o1 = new  ObjectWithDoubleValue (3.0);
  ObjectWithDoubleValue  o2 = new  ObjectWithDoubleValue (1.0);
  ObjectArray[] b = {o1 , o2};
  double maxB = ?;
```

Comment: How do you get the value from the object? Probably something like `Arrays.stream(b).map(o -> o.getValue()).sum();`

Comment: I suppose `ObjectWithDoubleValue[] b = {o1 , o2};` is what you want instead of `ObjectArray[] b = {o1 , o2};`

Comment: for (ObjectArray actualO : b){
         max += actualO.getValue();
      }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mapToDouble` which will return a `DoubleStream` and use `getter` function of your class to get value from your object and eventually apply `sum`

```
Arrays.stream(aa).mapToDouble(ObjectWithDoubleValue::getValue).sum()
```

where `getValue` is a `getter` function of your class

```
class ObjectWithDoubleValue{
    double a;
    public double getValue(){
        return a;
    }
}
```

---

Sample

```
ObjectWithDoubleValue a1= new ObjectWithDoubleValue();
a1.a=3.0;

ObjectWithDoubleValue a2= new ObjectWithDoubleValue();
a2.a=3.0;
ObjectWithDoubleValue[] aa={a1,a2};
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(aa).mapToDouble(ObjectWithDoubleValue::getValue).sum());
```

Output :

```
6.0
```

Comment: yes that was the perfect solution which solved my problem, i am very thankful, and sorry to everyone this was my first post and i dont know how to do a well format on this website.

Comment: @Gotti92 i am glad that i could help , happy coding